# Setting a label's for attribute to a DOM element, not an ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Short Question:**
How do you link a label element to an input element without using the input element's id using jQuery and javascript?

**Long Question:**
I am using jQuery to clone a form with possibly more than one instance of the form being available for the user to fill in.

A label's 'for' attribute is supposed to be set to the 'id' attribute of the input element that it is for.  This works when the input element has a unique id.

Because I am cloning the same input element there will be multiple input elements with the same id in the document.  Therefore I'm avoiding having id attributes for input elements but I'd still like to focus on the input element when the label is clicked.  I also want to avoid generating random ids for fields or setting onclick events on labels.

Edit #1

Example mark up (note no ids)

```
<form>    
<label>First Name:</label><input type='text' name='FirstName' /><br/>
<label>Last Name:</label><input type='text' name='LastName' /><br/>
</form>
```

Example cloning code:

```
var newForm = $('form').clone();

$(newForm).find('label').each(function(){
   var inputElement = $(this).next('input');

   // I'd love to set the label's for attribute to an element
   $(this).attr('for', inputElement);

});

$(document).append(newForm);
```

Edit #2

There currently are three options:

- Set onclick events for labels to focus on the input field they're for.  Criteria for deciding which labels are for which inputs can be the next input element or something else
- Embed the input fields in the label fields (might not be possible due to designer's choices)
- Generate random ids while cloning each form

Comment: I've accepted Amin's answer because I ended up using the onclick idea.  Paul Rosania's idea was valid too but I couldn't use it because the designer's design prohibits embedding the input in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it would be nice to see the markup, but if i can assume that the markup will look somewhat like this

```
<form name="f1">
<label>this is my label</label>
<input />
<label>this is my other label</label>
<input />
</form>

<form name="f2">
<label>this is my label</label>
<input />
<label>this is my other label</label>
<input />
</form>
```

then you could do something like this

```
$('form label').live('click',function(){
  $(this).next('input').focus();
});
```

you will need to use live or delegate since you're cloning the forms on the fly i'm assuming.

Comment: This answer is way better than mine.  I don't think I understood the question fully.

Comment: Thanks for that Amin.  I did say in my question that I'd like to avoid setting onclick events on the labels but if it turns out that I just can't set a label's for attribute to an element object then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @emurano Ahh, just noticed that :) i'll noodle on it a bit longer

Comment: It's a bit simpler if the form control is a child of the label, then the listener just has to look for a child that is a form control and only has to do it in IE (not sure if there's a feature test for that though).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to move the `<input>` tags inside the `<label>` tags and forgo the `for` attribute altogether.  Per the HTML spec, `<input>` tags without `for` attributes are implicitly associated with their contents.

Try this:

```
<form>    
  <label>First Name: <input type='text' name='FirstName' /></label><br/>
  <label>Last Name: <input type='text' name='LastName' /></label><br/>
</form>
```

(See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple identical ids in the page.  It defeats the purpose of the id attribute and is [against the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors).

Regardless, jQuery's `$(this)` could help you in this situation.  Say you gave all your the "focusable" class.  Then you could do:

```
$('.focusable').focus( function(){
     $(this).doSomething(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really an HTML question. A label can be associated wtih a form control either by its *for* attribute having the same value as the associated control's *id* attribute, or by having the control as a child of the label, e.g.

```
<form ...>

    <label for="nameField">Name:<input id="nameField" name="nameField" ... ></label>

    <label>email:<input name="emailField" ... ></label>

</form>
```

I suppose in jQuery you need something like:

```
var labelAndInput = $('<label>text<input ... ></label>');
```

or whatever. Note that older versions of IE (and maybe more recent ones too) the label will not be associated with the control without the *for* attribute (or *htmlFor* property), there is no other way.

Comment: The question is about dynamically cloning a form multiple times.  You can't have two or more elements with the same id.

Comment: Ah right you're suggesting just making the input element a child element of the label. That will inherently focus the input element when the label is clicked.